# Angular 2 querySelector and addeventlistener

Tags: angular, dom, typescript

```
onload = function() {
  var fcBody = document.querySelector(".fix-column > .tbody"),
      rcBody = document.querySelector(".rest-columns > .tbody"),
      rcHead = document.querySelector(".rest-columns > .thead");
  rcBody.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
      fcBody.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
      rcHead.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
  });
};
```

Trying to figure the above code out in the Angular 2 way. So far I've come up with using ViewChild and then trying to add event listeners. I've found something to do with HostListener but it got a little complex

```
@ViewChild('fcBody') fcBody: any;
@ViewChild('rcBody') rcBody: any;
@ViewChild('rcHead') rcHead: any;

ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.rcBody.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    this.fcBody.scrollTop = this.rcBody.scrollTop;
    this.rcHead.scrollLeft = this.rcBody.scrollLeft;
    });
}
```

I'd prefer to avoid using a directive if possible but if it's the best solution so be it.

Comment: do you think your post convey enough information?

Comment: I think so, it looks like I want to get a hold of three dom elements, then add an event listener to one of them the way I am supposed to do it in angular 2. If you didn't get that, feel free to suggest edits so my intent is clearer.

Comment: What about using (scroll)="scrollHandler()" on the `rcBody` element and `[scrollTop]="scrollTop" on the `fcBody` element?

Comment: That's interesting didn't know there was a scroll directive, so I can probably use events to get the values I'm looking for.  I'll give this a try and hopefully it works, thanks Gunter your answers are always very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Following Gunter's comment I did the following

```
<div #fcBody [scrollTop]="scrollTop" class="tbody">
<div #rcHead [scrollLeft]="scrollLeft" class="thead">
<div #rcBody (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)" class="tbody">

scrollHandler(event){
    this.scrollTop = event.srcElement.scrollTop;
    this.scrollLeft = event.srcElement.scrollLeft;
}
```

It worked perfectly. Essentially it makes the header of a scrollable header scroll with a scrollable table, and the frozen columns scroll with the scrollable table vertically.